# How do I migrate a java API to Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

**I'm new to foundry.** I have a java API that hit's the Moody's autocycle API to get all the information about particular cars the data is requested for. How do I migrate this API to Foundry, take input, call the API, and get data back and store it in objects and create dashboards?

I created a requested_data object, turned it into an action form, and embedded the form in a Workshop to take user input.
Now this input will get stored in the object REQUEST_TABLE. I need the workflow to take this input, call the API with this information, and get data back into a new object called RESULT_TABLE.